# Visibilily in #inject:into: block

Tags: smalltalk

This code:

```
((1 to: 10)
    inject: (WriteStream on: String new)
    into: [ :strm :each |
        ((each rem: 3) = 0)
            ifTrue: [
                strm
                    nextPutAll: each printString;
                    space;
                    yourself ]]) contents
```

fails because `strm` is undefined where it is used in the `ifTrue:` block. Why is it not visible there?

Edit: I tried it out in VASt and Pharo.

Comment: Which dialect are you using? Dolphin, VW, VA, Pharo, Squeak, GNU...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the implied `ifFalse:` branch returns `nil`. To fix this, try the following:

```
((1 to: 10)
    inject: (WriteStream on: String new)
    into: [ :strm :each |
        ((each rem: 3) = 0)
            ifFalse: [strm]  "This is needed to avoid nil being returned"
            ifTrue: [
                strm
                    nextPutAll: each printString;
                    space;
                    yourself ]]) contents
```

Comment: This works, but I still do not quite understand. Is it necessary to return the `strm` in the first cycle (in the `ifFalse:` block) for it to be "initialized"?

Comment: Forget the comment above, I do understand it. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the dialect (methods available), you can take much shorter approach

```
((1 to: 10) select: [ :each | (each rem: 3) = 0 ]) joinUsing: ' '
```

As a rule of thumb¹, any `collection do: [ :each | something ifTrue: [] ]` can be turned into much more straight-forward and readable `collection select: []` or `collection reject: []`

Doing so will spread out the complexity over several independent steps (1. filtering, 2. adding to stream), instead of shoving it all together.

Or if you want to stick to your original

```
(((1 to: 10) select: [ :each | (each rem: 3) = 0 ])
    inject: (WriteStream on: String new)
    into: [ :stream :each |
        stream
            nextPutAll: each printString;
            space;
            yourself ]) contents
```

or

```
String streamContents: [ :stream |
    (1 to: 10)
        select: [ :each | (each rem: 3) = 0 ]
        thenDo: [ :each |
            stream
                nextPutAll: each printString;
                space
        ]
]
```

---

¹So not always, but always good to keep in mind when you encounter such situation.

Comment: You are quite correct. This sample was sub-part of a fizzbuzz implementation I was showing a colleague, which cannot be reduced to `select:` or `reject:`.